# Why does ELB have its own account IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb

I was setting up AWS infra through Terraform and realized I have to allow ELB account IDs access to write in S3 for writing the logs. Why does ELB have its own account ID in different regions and what does it signify? Check the image below (taken from here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For regions available before 2022, you need to use ELB account ID as service name which is the list of ID's that you mentioned above.

> **A service principal is an identifier for a service.**

First, it should be noted that it is used as an identifier for `Service Pricipal Name`. Looks like AWS has hard coded the service principals for ELB's and it is not a different AWS account.

Regions available as of August 2022 or later the Service Principal Name looks like

```
"Principal": {
        "Service": "logdelivery.elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
      },
```

And for regions available before August 2022

```
"Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
```

To know what is a Service Principal refer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-services